# Where to find QNX SP1 (not QNX SDP SP1)

Tags: installation, qnx

I might be getting something wrong about QNX since I'm new to it. But I'm confused by `QNX 6.5.0 Service Pack 1` AND `QNX SDP 6.5.0 Service Pack 1`, which I assume are two different things. And I'm told by my client that I need to install the former (non-SDP one). Where can I get it?

With being logged in, [my account page](https://www.qnx.com/account/index.html) tells that:

```
Download QNX SDP v6.5 Service Pack 1

QNX SDP 6.5 Service Pack 1 offers improved OS performance, services and updated drivers – and is now available for download.
Download QNX 6.5.0 SP1 now
```

```

The last line is a link that takes me [here](http://www.qnx.com/download/group.html?programid=20905), where all links say that they are SDP SP1 except 1 link provides QNX 6.5.0 SP1 virtual machine. VM is actually good for for me for testing but can't be integrated into my non-VM instance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self response. [Someone is saying](http://community.qnx.com/sf/discussion/do/listPosts/projects.community/discussion.community.topc23726?_message=1371675476995) that `SDP SP1` is a superset of `Momentics tool suite` and (for self-hosted) the `QNX Neutrino` OS itself. Thus `SDP SP1` suffices.

Answer (score 2):

QNX SDP is the Software Development Platform for QNX. Typically you would use the System Builder component to create an OS image that contains various runtime binary or other files. You would then install that OS image on your target system.

Service Pack 1 is only available for the SDP or as a VM image for evaluation. There is no standalone installer to put SP1 onto an existing target system, since it checks your license key when you install it. It also contains various software development tools that may have a license incompatible to the one you are distributing on your target systems (e.g. the QNX software is paid for so you can't simply distribute it, or the GPL software could have ramifications for your own target system).

What you are meant to do is install SP1 on your already existing QNX SDP 6.5.0 (i.e. the computer you do the software development on), rebuild your OS image which will now contain the new SP1 files and then re-deploy that to your target system.

Comment: Actually I've resolved [my question in Foundry27 website](http://community.qnx.com/sf/discussion/do/listPosts/projects.community/discussion.community.topc23726?_pagenum=3) but thanks for even clearer answer.